# How to get xpath contains another xpath?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have a table row count, inside that I have one text. I want to get in which row that text is present with selenium.

I want to get the row index number(`TBLROW#`) in which `G-28` text/element is present.

[image: Please refer the image here:]

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, Hope this helps.

```
List<WebElement> elements=driver.findelements(By.xpath(//tr[contains(@class,'TABLROW')]//b))

int rownumber=0;
for(i=0; i < elements.size();i++)
{

rownumber=i;
if(elements.get(i).gettext().contains("G-28"))
{
   break;
}

}
```

rownumber should give the row number